# convert julian date to calendar date YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: mysql, julian-date

Julian Date format
20202800234036

The first four-digit are year -2020

and 356 is the day of the year.

what will be the format for this in mysql to achieve it after taking in 7 first values.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: There's no 356 here

Comment: Where do people use Julian dates? I don't think this question makes that much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `str_to_date('2020356','%Y%j')` (gives 2020-12-21) , where `%Y` is the format specifier for a four-digit year, and `%j` is the day of the year.

For the longer date referenced in your question, just take the `LEFT('20202800234036',7)` and apply STR_TO_DATE()` to that:

`str_to_date(LEFT('20202800234036',7),'%Y%j')   -- 2020-10-06`

There's a reference for these formats [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: the Julian format is 20202800234036 
we have to take only first seven digits. 

2020280 - so i have to split it first, any function for it.